# Idiomatically buffer os.Stdout

Tags: go

`os.Stdout.Write()` is an *unbuffered* write. To get a *buffered* write, one can use the following:

```
f := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
f.Write(b)
```

**Question:**

Is there a more idiomatic way to get *buffered* output?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

No, that is the most idiomatic way to buffer writes to Stdout. In many cases, you will want to also add a defer:

```
f := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
defer f.Flush()
f.Write(b)
```

This will ensure that the buffer is flushed when you return from the function.

Comment: I also like sizing it: `var STDOUT     = bufio.NewWriterSize(os.Stdout, 4096)` and then writing to it like `fmt.Fprint(STDOUT, "output")`.