# Why does reading from StdoutPipe changes order of output?

Tags: go, stdout

I have the following function which calls a command which I cannot publish here. Previous I used `cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout` to get the commands output on my command line like this, which worked fine:

```golang
func run(cmd *exec.Cmd) {
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return
}
```

This gives me the following command line output, which is great:

```
[loader] loading programm...
[programm] foo bar
```

Now I need to interact with the output first, so I tried using  `StdoutPipe`:

```
func run(cmd *exec.Cmd) {
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    reader := bufio.NewReader(stdout)
    for {
        s, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        //  do some evaluation of s here
        fmt.Print(s)
    }
    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return
}
```

But this messes up the order of the messages, I no get the following output:

```
[programm] foo bar
[loader] loading programm...
```

Why is the output not in order anymore and how can I keep it in order while using stdoutPipe?

**EDIT:**
The same is happening if I try to use `io.MultiWriter` like this:

```golang
func run(cmd *exec.Cmd) {
    var reader bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, &reader)
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for {
        s, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        fmt.Print(s)
    }
    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: I can not reproduce the described behavior with given information. https://play.golang.org/p/UM1Mczfk2Kp Either you run into a bug specific to your version of the runtime and/or os. Either you have a bug within the `runner` thing, but if you cannot demonstrate the bug, we can not help.

Comment: @mh-cbon thanks for your answer, since the runner did nothing than the basic exec functions, I adjusted the code a little. I thought I might oversee some obvious error in my code, thanks for trying to reproduce it.

Comment: which verson of the runtime / os  are you are using that faces that problem ?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04, Go 1.16.2

Comment: i still can not reproduce using a dockerfile https://pastebin.pl/view/151cd8da

Comment: The command may be buffering writes to stdout when stdout is not a tty.

Comment: @CeriseLimón how would that disorder the output by itself ? I dont see

Comment: Thanks @CeriseLimón, you were right. I used `stdbuf -o0` to deactivate the buffering.

Comment: @mh-cbon  The displayed output order will change if the application also writes to stderr.

Comment: Does your program maybe output things randomly?

Comment: @gonutz no, this does not happen randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great deal depends on the program you run.

You [noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66744788/why-does-reading-from-stdoutpipe-changes-order-of-output#comment117988939_66744788) that:

> I used `stdbuf -o0` to deactivate the buffering

This only affects the program's `stdout` (file descriptor 1 on a POSIX system), not its `stderr` (file descriptor 2).  But POSIX systems generally use the following defaults, at least for C-language programs or those that make use of the C runtime system:

- stdin: buffering is not particularly relevant, but input will usually be fully buffered.
- stdout: line buffered if file descriptor 1 is a "tty"; fully buffered otherwise.
- stderr: unbuffered.

The determination of what is a "tty" is done by calling the C library `isatty` function, which generally uses a [termios](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/termios.h.html) operation to do this.  For instance, the [glibc `isatty`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/posix/isatty.c.html) calls `tcgetattr` and verifies that it returns without error.  The [glibc tcgetattr](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/tcgetattr.c.html) uses the `TCGETATTR` [ioctl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html).  So a "tty device" is one that implements `TCGETATTR`.

Actual serial lines (COM1 and COM2 for instance), as used in the old days, or terminal concentrator devices such as the DH/DM or DZ in the *really* old days, of course implement `TCGETATTR`.  So do pseudo-terminals, such as those employed by interactive `ssh` sessions, `script`, and other programs.  This enables all that old software from the 1970s and 1980s to continue working with the virtualized [ASR33](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletype_Model_33), [ADM3A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM-3A), or [DECwriter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DECwriter) to continue to work.<sup>1</sup>

Anyway, the key here is that a *pipe*—or a socket or similar—*does not* implement `TCGETATTR`, so if stdout is a pipe, then `isatty(1)` is 0 (false).  That makes stdout *fully buffered*.

Remember, this is all happening in *the program you run*.  Your own program, reading the output from that other program, is not (necessarily) the problem.  Your program only *gets* output when that other program actually *sends* it.  In fully-buffered modes, that other program only *sends* output when it fills up a buffer block, or calls some output-flushing operation.

Some programs mix output to stdout—which they often *assume* is line buffered, as the human who wrote the (defective) program only tested it with tty output—and output to stderr.  These programs behave oddly when stdout is redirected to a file or pipe.  Programs like `stdbuf`—which may be implemented as a library preload, and [hence might not work on setuid programs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279984/stdbuf-supposed-behavior-for-subprocesses)—can be used to work around these problems.

In Go, buffering is much more up to your own program.  Go does not use the POSIX setup.  See [Idiomatically buffer os.Stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13422381/1256452) for example.

---

<sup>1</sup>I like my virtual Tek4025, Heathkit H19, etc., better, though there's something to be said for the old printing terminals!  Or the old AAA terminal, with up to 60 lines in Squint Mode.  OK, Terminal, iterm2, etc. have them beat.